# what is the physical meaning of transconductance?

Tags: bjt, graph

i know for a BJT transconductance is the slope of the collector current to the base-emitter voltage difference plot..
ans also it is equal to the slope of the collector current to the thermal voltage Vt = (nk)/q
where n can be 1 or 2 and k is boltzman const

but what all this physically means..
what is the use of transconductance?

Answer (score 2):

> Transconductance is a property of certain electronic components. Conductance is the reciprocal of resistance; transconductance is the ratio of the current change at the output port to the voltage change at the input port. It is written as \$g_m\$. For direct current, transconductance is defined as follows:
>
> \$g_m = {\Delta I_\mathrm{out} \over \Delta V_\mathrm{in}} \$
>
> For small signal alternating current, the definition is simpler:
>
> \$g_m = {i_\mathrm{out} \over v_\mathrm{in}} \$
>
> [image]

Courtsey of [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transconductance).

It's use is simple: it's used to mathematically model any device where some current is a function of some voltage. Vacuum tubes, field effect transistors, and bipolar transistors can all be modelled as such, as well as many circuits composed of them.